# Append a copy of an element containing an input

Tags: jquery, html

So here is my JS:

```
$('.options_button').click(function() {
    $( ".new_input" ).last().clone().appendTo( ".options" );
});
```

and here is my HTML:

```
              <div class="options">
                <h2>Options</h2>
                <span class="input input--kuro">
                    <input id="inputID" class="input__field input__field--kuro" type="text" id="input-7" placeholder="..." />
                    <label class="input__label input__label--kuro" for="input-7"></label>
                </span>
                <span class="input input--kuro">
                    <input id="inputID" class="input__field input__field--kuro" type="text" id="input-8" placeholder="..."/>
                    <label class="input__label input__label--kuro" for="input-8"></label>
                </span>
                <span class="input input--kuro new_input">
                    <input id="inputID" class="input__field input__field--kuro" type="text" id="input-9" placeholder="..."/>
                    <label class="input__label input__label--kuro" for="input-9"></label>
                </span>
            </div>
            <button class="options_button">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                <p>Option</p>
            </button>
```

Clicking my button clones one of the spans that contains an input (and label) and appends it below the others. I thought I was being clever, but the problem is that it doesn't just clone the blank input field, but when the input is filled it also clones what has been entered too. So clearly cloning the input is not the way forward.

Can anyone give me an idea of how I can modify what I have done? I know it's possible to just add new inputs using jQuery, but I don't just want to do that, I want to add blank copies of the span and the label and input that it contains.

Comment: As I understood you want something like that http://jsbin.com/bupof/1/edit?js,output

Comment: That's absolutely perfect! Cheers you're a star!

Comment: first of all your id's should be unique within the document.

Comment: Thanks, I know. In trying to get something unrelated to this to work I copied the way someone else had done it. My plan was always to chnage them to classes once i got it working.

Comment: @Billy You're a genius. I've been struggling with something else all day and it turns out that the reason it wasn't working was literally because I was using ID when I should have been using classes. I always thought you shouldn't use IDs just because it wouldn't validate. I had no idea that the reason JS .map was only saving my first input to an array was because it can only take one ID. Changing them all to classes now saves all of my inputs to an array and it all works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.options_button').click(function() {
    $( ".new_input" ).last().clone().appendTo( ".options" ).find('input').val('');
});
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/bupof/1/edit?js,output)